# Calling the variable outside the plugin file and inside the function file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

**I completely edited my question.**

I use the YITH WooCommerce Compare plugin, I will put the file that contains the codes that are related to my question : https://file.io/StHr7KBJBdxF

`$current_cat` variable has been set equal to : `public $current_cat = array();`, `$this->current_cat` has been used in some parts of the code, How to call the `$this->current_cat` outside the file and in the function file?

```
class YITH_Woocompare_Frontend_Premium extends YITH_Woocompare_Frontend {

    …

    /**
     * The list of current cat inside the comparison table
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @var array
     */
    public $current_cat = array();
```

For example: used a `$this->products_list;`, If I want to call it outside the file and in the function file, it goes like this : `$products_list = isset( $_COOKIE[ get_cookie_name() ] ) ? json_decode( wp_unslash( $_COOKIE[ get_cookie_name() ] ) ) : array();`

I hope you understand what I mean. If this is a beginner's question, please don't diss because not everyone is a professional like you. Also, I spent a lot of time solving the problem. It's not like I want to quickly ask my question here to quickly find an answer.

Comment: You're providing a lot of code for people to read through. 
Is there a way you can simplify this code, so that it still demonstrates your problem, but reduces the workload for those who want to help you? 

Maybe you can eliminate `if` statements that aren't necessary to recreate the problem, and also perhaps some other logic isn't needed for this purpose (e.g. all the things you do for different values of `$fields`)

Comment: hi SimonMayer, I could have put one code, but I said maybe I should put all the codes so they can understand better, I put the summarized codes in the summary section.

Comment: I get that you're trying to put extra context to be helpful, but IMO, you're likely to get more effective help if you can provide the simplest possible example that demonstrates your problem, and minimize the amount of unnecessary reading. You're relying on people giving up their time, and in general, they aren't going to want to invest lots of time into understanding your program, but they can be most effective if you help them focus in on exactly where it's going wrong, and remove any details that are not necessary to the problem you're reporting.

Comment: SimonMayer, I completely edited my question.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer about the bit you're referring to: the public $current_cat property within the YITH_Woocompare_Frontend_Premium class

Comment: If you have an object that instantiates that class, e.g. `$someObject = new YITH_Woocompare_Frontend_Premium();`, then maybe your answer is as simple as calling `$someObject->current_cat`.  However, I do not have the knowledge of woocommerce or this plugin to help you further with what you're trying to do.  But hopefully now the question is at least in a state for others to guide you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much effort, I was able to call `$current_cat` variable outside the plugin and in the function file without the YITH WooCommerce Compare plugin installed.

```
function get_product_categories( $product_id ) {
    $cat        = array();
    $categories = array();
    if ( ! is_array( $product_id ) ) {
        $categories = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    } else {
        foreach ( $product_id as $id ) {
            $single_cat = get_the_terms( $id, 'product_cat' );
            if ( empty( $single_cat ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $single_values = array_values( $single_cat );
            $categories = array_merge( $categories, $single_values );
        }
    }
    if ( empty( $categories ) ) {
        return $cat;
    }
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        if ( ! $category ) {
            continue;
        }
        $cat[ $category->term_id ] = $category->name;
    }
    return apply_filters( 'yith_woocompare_get_product_categories', $cat, $categories, $product_id );
}

function get_cookie_name() {
    $suffix = '';
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        $suffix = '_' . get_current_blog_id();
    } elseif ( '/' !== COOKIEPATH ) {
        $suffix = '_' . sanitize_title( COOKIEPATH );
    }
    return 'yith_woocompare_list' . $suffix;
}

$products_list = isset( $_COOKIE[ get_cookie_name() ] ) ? json_decode( wp_unslash( $_COOKIE[ get_cookie_name() ] ) ) : array();
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['yith_compare_cat'] ) ) {
    $current_cat = array( absint( $_REQUEST['yith_compare_cat'] ) );
} elseif ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    $current_cat = $categories;
} elseif ( ! empty( $products_list ) ) {
    $products    = $products_list;
    $product     = array_pop( $products );
    $categories  = array_keys( get_product_categories( $product ) );
    $current_cat = $categories;
} else {
    $current_cat = $categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `current_cat` is a [*public property*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) of a [*class*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) defined by your plugin.

Within functions that are part of that same class, code can access that property with `$this->current_cat`. Why?  `$this` is, inside that class's code, a reference to the current instance of the class. The `->` *object operator* tells php to look inside `$this`.

Outside that class's code you can access public properties like so.

```php
$my_object = new PluginClass();
$cat = $my_object->current_cat;
```

You are trying to do the thing shown in the second line of that example. To do it you need access to the variable returned by `new PluginClass()` in the first line. Different plugins have different ways of making that kind of information available to theme code (functions.php). It's necessary to look at the plugin's code to figure out how to do that, or look at the documentation, or consult the plugin's support forum.

With respect, explaining how php classes work is too complex for a Stack Overflow answer. So is explaining how WordPress, plugins, and theme code interact. I hope this answer points you in a useful direction.

Comment: O. Jones, Thank you for your time and answering my question. In fact, I put the codes of this plugin into the function and created the comparison system without the plugin and everything is fine, the only problem is that when I click on the filter by category, the results all show the same category. And with my search in the codes, I realized that I didn't set the $current_cat variable correctly, that's why I asked this question, how to set the $current_cat variable without a plugin.

Comment: In the file I placed, the `exclude_product_from_list` function is responsible for listing the list based on the current category, In that function, the value I considered for `$current_cat` variable is as follows : `$product = array_pop( $products ); $categories = array_keys( get_product_categories( $product ) ); $current_cat = $categories;`, But when I click on the filter of each category, the list of one category is displayed, that is, the list based on the current category does not work properly, the problem is the valuing of the `$current_cat` variable.